# How to make flash content to work on mobile devices?

Tags: android, flash, media-player

I've seen that some websites that offer video playing services have made their videos work on Android phones, while others dont. Those that work are being opened using the phone's Video Player or other apps such as MX Player.

How can I do this on my website? I know that there is the HTML5 alternative but for some reason I can't implement that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options to stream videos to mobile browsers:

- [HLS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Streaming) (HTTP Live Streaming) for Apple devices

  - H.264 encoding
  - Streaming server e.g. [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/media-server/features)
- [WebM](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) streaming to Androids and other devices

  - Browser support in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Android browser
  - VP8 encoding
  - Streaming server e.g. [stream-m](http://code.google.com/p/stream-m/)
- [MotionJPEG](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)

  - Works for non-audio videos
  - Works on almost all devices
  - Choppy playback, as there is no inter-frame compression
- Flash Player

  - Only few mobile devices, market share steadily vanishes
  - Supports streaming or progressive download
  - Streaming server e.g. [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/media-server/features) or [Red5](http://www.red5.org)

If your video must not necessarily play back in the browser, you can also just provide a download link to your video. Please note that you won't profit from streaming features like seeking and saving bandwidth for unplayed parts of the video then. In any case, you need to encode your video in different bitrates/codecs to be able to target all devices.